# Die Möglichkeiten sind groß

Tags: phrase, synonym

Intuitiv ist mir klar, was durch "die Möglichkeiten sind groß" - etwa in einem politischen Kontext - ausgedrückt wird, jedoch fällt es mir schwer, eine passende Umschreibung zu finden.

Welches Adjektiv/welche Phrase könnte man hier statt "groß" einsetzen?

Comment: Ehrlich gesagt, finde ich "Die Möglichkeiten sind groß" eher schwach formuliert. Anstelle der Möglichkeiten selbst ist wohl eher dern Anzahl oder die Auswahl zwischen ihnen groß.

Comment: Möglichkeiten sind nicht groß. Möglichkeiten sind entweder gut ("Das ist eine gute Möglichkeit, Deutsch zu lernen.") oder zahlreich ("Die Webseite bietet zahlreiche Möglichkeiten, Deutsch zu lernen.").

Comment: Die Möglichkeiten können auch vielfältig sein.

Answer (score 3):

- Es gibt viele Möglichkeiten
- Der Möglichkeiten sind viele
- Uns stehen viele Optionen offen

Durch Hulk in den Kommentaren:

- Es eröffnen sich [ungeahnte/zahlreiche/unzählige/großartige] Möglichkeiten

Comment: Daran habe ich auch gedacht, es fehlt aber die positive Konnotation von "groß".

Comment: Oder "Es eröffnen sich [ungeahnte/zahlreiche/unzählige/großartige] Möglichkeiten", je nach Kontext

Comment: Das ist nicht wirklich synonym...

Comment: @Carlster Ich denke, du solltest deine Frage überarbeiten, wenn dir die Antwort hier nicht treffend erscheint. So wie deine Frage steht, ist das hier eine passende Antwort. Auf der anderen Seite, kann man genau so gut für "not a real question" close-voten. Welche Konnotation verstehst du eigentlich unter "groß", wenn dir die Beispiele hier nicht nah genug an deinem Satz dran sind?

Answer (score 1):

Direkte Alternativen sind zum Beispiel:

> zahlreich, mannigfaltig (Fokus auf Quantität)

Ansonsten gibt es wohl sehr viele Umschreibungen:

> Es bieten sich/eröffnen sich/gibt großartige/viele Möglichkeiten.
>
> Da geht viel. (wird mittlerweile auch in der Politik benutzt)
>
> Wir haben eine einmalige Chance.
>
> Es ist ein günstiger Moment/günstiges Zeitfenster
>
> Die Situation war nie besser geeignet, um ... zu

Answer (score 1):

Ich sehe hier 2 unterschiedliche, mögliche Bedeutungen; beide nicht gut getroffen:

a) Die Chancen sind groß/hoch. Beispiel: Die Fischschwärme schwimmen auf uns zu; wir müsen nur zupacken.

b) Der Möglichkeiten sind viele. Wir haben 3000 Euro und wollen zu zweit in Urlaub fahren. Die Zahl der Möglichkeiten ist groß.

Beide Male sind die Möglichkeiten nicht groß, sondern entweder die Chance oder die Zahl der Möglichkeiten oder beides.